# (or maybe more)Clojure background process

Tags: clojure, cron, daemon, leiningen

Let's say Im making a crawler / scraper in clojure, and I want it to run periodically (at predefined times of day).

I want to define my jobs with quartz / quartzite (at least that seems to be the most robust solution.)

Now, to create a daemon process with clojure, I tried lein-daemon plugin, but it seems that it is a pretty risky endevour, since the plugin seems more than a bit buggy (or I am making some heavy mistakes)

What is the best way for me to create this service?
I want it to be able to restart itself upon system reboot, but I want to use clojure (quartzite) for my jobs (loading them from database, etc).

What is the robust - but clojury - way to create a long-running, daemon process?

EDIT:

The deployment environment will be something like a single VPS or a dedicated server.
There may be a dozen jobs loading their parameters from some data store, running anywhere from 1 - 8 times a day (or maybe more).

Comment: I am not an expert for java, so the less code I need to do directly in java, the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct process depends a lot on your environment. I work on deployment systems for complex web/mobile infrastructure with many long running Clojure processes. For this we use [Pallet to create instances with the code](http://palletops.com/) checked out and configured, then we have a function that generates init scripts to start the services at boot. This process is appropriate to environments where you need a repeatable build on a cloud provider so it may be too heavy for your situation.

If you are looking for simple recurring jobs you may want to look into [Immutant](http://immutant.org/) which is an **application server for Clojure** with good support for [recurring jobs](http://immutant.org/tutorials/jobs/index.html).

Comment: Yes, pallet would be an overkill at this phase.
I edited my question.

Comment: +1, I'm checking Immutant... If it delivers all it promises.. It will be a very pleasant surprise..

Comment: Seems like Immutant is what I'm after.